# Location of .dtbs files - specifically uart0.dts and minimart-bt.dts

Tags: raspbian, device-tree

Does anyone know where I can find the precompiled `.dtbs` files - specifically `uart0.dts` and `minimart-bt.dts`?

Comment: *.dts files are the SOURCE - did you want the compiled files - i.e the .dtbo files (no idea what a .dtbs file is) - they're in `/boot/overlays`

Answer (score 2):

To find files you can use the `find` command, for example to look for `*.dts` files:

```
rpi ~$ sudo find / -xdev -iname *.dts
```

Answer (score 0):

Their source code is at https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/tree/rpi-5.4.y/arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays/. The compiled files (They can be converted back to source using dtc) are att /boot/overlays.